# Enlarging images in dv

Tags: html, css, image

How would I make the images here take up more of the content div in the media query? There is too much left and right space that I can't remove.

http://codepen.io/kiddigit/pen/EKRgQz

```
    .content {
        border: 1px solid red; 
        margin-left: 90px;
        margin-right: 90px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top:0px;
    }
```

Comment: You could try using placeholder images to easier show what you want in your demo. Something like: http://placehold.it/400x400

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll do that going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps change the `max-width` of image from 50% to 100% and remove the `margin-left: 90px;` and `margin-right: 90px;` of the container.

You can also add `width:100%` to `img` to get the images sticked to the red border.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaJQOJ)

Comment: This is great. Thanks, Vincent G. Super helpful. Sorry for the newbie question.